# Counting emails in gmail in google sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Maybe this is a basic question, but I can find the answer.  How can you make an automatic count of received letters with a specific label.  That is, I thought to post a trigger so that every day at 01-02 o'clock in the morning, the letters for yesterday would be counted.  And so it will fill up every day.  Example file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jqtHVwab5qqhGgfpFt4J5uQraZU0BIzD2B6mNT9mX0w/edit

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet that is written in English? please indicate where do you expect the email count be added? In addition, can you confirm that you want to get the email count received with a specific label within 24 hours prior the time you execute the script? example you run it today 06/17/2021 at 1:00, then the email that will be counted will be from 06/16/2021 1:00 up to 06/17/2021 12:59?

Comment: Hello.  
Added titles in English on the sheet.  I want to count on 06/17/21 at 01:00 how many messages were with a certain label between 00:00 and 23:59 on 06/16/21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use this sample code (Just replace the `label`):

```
function countEmailyesterday(){

  const secondsSinceEpoch = (date) => Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
  const after = new Date();
  const before = new Date();


  //Subtract 1 day 
  after.setDate(after.getDate()-1);
  before.setDate(before.getDate()-1);

  //Get -1 day  date string
  var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var todayStr = Utilities.formatDate(after,timezone,"dd.MM.yyyy");
  Logger.log(todayStr);

  //Set time to 00:00 and 23:59
  after.setHours(00, 00, 0, 0);
  before.setHours(23, 59, 0, 0);
  
  //Label
  const label = "Гимнастика Диана";
  const query = `label:${label} after:${secondsSinceEpoch(after)} before:${secondsSinceEpoch(before)}`;
  Logger.log(query);

  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var count = threads.length;
  Logger.log(count);

  //Find the matching date's row and write the email count in column B
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Monitor');
  var dateValues = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getDisplayValues().flat();
  Logger.log(dateValues);
  //find matched index
  var index = dateValues.indexOf(todayStr);
  if(index!=-1){
    Logger.log(index);
    sheet.getRange(index+1,2).setValue(count);
  }
}
```

### What it does?

1. Create a `before` and `after` date object based on today's date.
2. Create a today's date string in this format `dd-MM-yyyy`
3. Subtract 1 day from each date object. Then set the time for `before` to `23:59:00` while `after` to `00:00:00`
4. Create a gmail query string using [Gmail search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) `label:(your label) after:(Epoch datetime) before:(Epoch datetime)`
5. Use [GmailApp.search(query)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery) which will return an array of [GmailThread](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread)
6. Get the length of the array.
7. Get the date values in column A as string using `Range.getDisplayValues()`. Use `array.flat()` to change the date values to 1-d array
8. Use `array.indexOf()` to find the array index of the matching date today
9. Use the array index (adding +1 offset since array is zero-based) as the row index in `Sheet.getRange(row,col)` and set column B value based on the email count.

### Output:

[image]

### Additional Reference:

- [How to Search Emails in Gmail by Specific Time](https://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-search-tips/29206/#:%7E:text=Search%20Emails%20by%20Specific%20Time%20in%20Gmail&text=To%20get%20started%2C%20convert%20the,8%3A45%20PM%20is%201602774900.)

Comment: hank you so much.
Yes, this is what I needed.
Another question is how to make the script itself fill in these lines relative to the date. That is, I can put a trigger on it, but how will the script understand that it is necessary to put in cell B18 the number of letters with the label "Collecting" for 06/21/17?

Comment: I updated the answer. Please let me know if you encountered an issue.

Comment: By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Yes, I ran into a small problem.
That the number of letters is put down in the column with the current date, although it should be put down and before. day.
<img src = "https://yadi.sk/i/UujEuyWIr7QPHg" width = "100" height = "100">

And another question, in my script file "Sent in a telegram" it sends a message if there is data in column B: B, and is it possible to add a condition so that when sending a message, the number of letters in the "Orders sent" column is summed up, if column B: B is empty?
<img src = "https://yadi.sk/i/CPxPPPhBdEtzWA" width = "200" height = "100">

Comment: Sorry for that. I updated the answer. The email count will be logged on the yesterday's date. Regarding your 2nd question, I did not fully understood your question? You want to get the sum of column B using apps script?

Comment: Yes, now what you need.
Thank you.

Yes, I want to calculate the sum of column E: E, when sending a message in telegram, if there is no data in column B: B for the previous day.
That is, for example, https://yadi.sk/i/CPxPPPhBdEtzWA
When sending for 15.06, the bot will send that Transferredorders are not 30, but 52

Comment: Can you create a separate post for that. It seems it is already a different goal from the original post

Comment: Hi
There was a small problem, I now have a date in column A:A in this format: thu, July 8, 2021.
It was I who set up such a display in the table itself, and now the script does not understand a little where to write the number.
How can I convert the date in the script to the same format?

Comment: I tried it this way: 

var date = new Date()
var date_line = Utilities.formatDate(date, "Europe/Moscow", "E, d MMY")
return LanguageApp.translate(date_line, 'en', 'ru')

But here the day of the week is obtained with a capital letter, and in the table with a small one, and because of this it does not converge for creaking.

Comment: use this `var date = new Date();
  var date_line = Utilities.formatDate(date, "Europe/Moscow", "E, MMMMMM d, yyyy");
  var tmp = date_line.split(",");
  tmp[0] = tmp[0].toLowerCase();
  date_line = tmp.join();
  Logger.log(date_line);`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
function countemailwithalabel() {
   const ts = GmailApp.search('label: qs-services-ups');
   let msgs = 0;
   ts.forEach(t => msgs+=t.getMessageCount());
   Logger.log(msgs);//6
}
```

Comment: Looks like what I need, thanks.  And how to add to this code the ability to filter exactly for yesterday and search by label name, as in 1 row?

Comment: I would not have a clue since I know nothing about your data and I do not follow links to offsite resources.  Post what is required in the question or live without help.